# Python if/elif simplification

Tags: python, if-statement, simplification

This is part of my code:

```
for line in f:
    if animals[0].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[1].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[2].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[3].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[4].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[5].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[6].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[7].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[8].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[9].upper() in line:
        break
    elif animals[10].upper() in line:
        break
    print(line)
```

I'm just trying to figure if it can be simplified somehow but I really can't come up with anything. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a loop that increases to 10, and use it instead of the numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a completely equivalent piece of code to what you have above:

```
if any(animals[x].upper() in line for x in range(11)):
    break
```

Assuming that `animals` supports the iterator protocol (which is likely true), an even better solution would be to do something like this:

```
if any(animal.upper() in line for animal in animals):  # slice animals as necessary
    break
```

Comment: `if line in map(str.upper, animals[:11])` ?

Comment: @JonClements -- I don't think so.  `line = "badger'; animals = ["badgers"]`.  Yours returns `True`, OP's returns `False`.  (The animals are supposed to be in the line, not the line in the animals).  Plus, it doesn't work on python3.x ;-)

Comment: dammit, you beat me to it! :P

Comment: I probably would have gone with `if any(animal.upper() in line for animal in animals[:11])`, or drop the slice if `animals` is always 11 elements long (which it probably is).

Comment: @user2357112 -- Yes, that is better.  Thanks.  (that's what I get for coding in the middle of the night.)